# Python regex not matching multiple groups

Tags: python, regex

My input string is:

```
{(metrics)(metrics)[(mapper_init)(mapper_init)(1)][(mapper_input_lines)(mapper_input_lines)(102571)]}
```

When I run the following code:

```
metric_matches = re.findall('(\[\(\w+\)\((\w+)\)\((\d+)\)\])+', metrics_line)

print "Processing: %s" % metrics_line
print metric_matches
```

I get:

```
Processing: {(metrics)(metrics)[(mapper_init)(mapper_init)(1)][(mapper_input_lines)(mapper_input_lines)(102571)]}
[('[(mapper_input_lines)(mapper_input_lines)(102571)]', 'mapper_input_lines', '102571')]
```

Why isn't it matching both groups? I'm trying to get it to match:

```
[(__not-important__, 'mapper_init', 1), (__not-important__, 'mapper_input_lines', '102571')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution (I had typo in previous one):

```
metric_matches = re.findall(r'\[\((\w+)\)\((\w+)\)\((\d+)\)\]', metrics_line)
```

Result will be:

```
[('mapper_init', 'mapper_init', '1'), ('mapper_input_lines', 'mapper_input_lines', '102571')]
```

As you can see brackets stay there, but `+` is removed.

Comment: he's trying to get all the consecutive bracketed groups to be combined into one match in the result. How does this help?

Comment: Thanks. It turns out it was the square brackets causing the problem. Once I removed the leading '\\[' and trailing '\\]' it worked.

Comment: yeh, I just noticed this. I'm trying to figure out why it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are unnecessary outermost `(` `)` brackets and a `+`. I'm not sure about your regex's requirement and other input case, but this regex will produce what you want in this case:

`>>> metric_matches = re.findall('\[\((\w+)\)\((\w+)\)\((\d+)\)\]', metrics_line)`

`>>> [('mapper_init', 'mapper_init', '1'), ('mapper_input_lines', 'mapper_input_lines', '102571')]`

If the first value in tuple is not important, then you can ignore it like:

`>>> metric_matches = re.findall('\[\(\w+\)\((\w+)\)\((\d+)\)\]', metrics_line)`

`>>> [('mapper_init', '1'), ('mapper_input_lines', '102571')]`